# How to refresh KieContainer Manually without using KieScanner?

Tags: spring-boot, drools, drools-guvnor, drools-planner

We are `Drools 7.2` version for our rule management. We can use `KieScanner` when we want to refresh `KieContainer` at a frequent interval by loading `.jar`. But in our case we are storing rules in `MongoDB` as a `String`. We need to load `drl` rules from `MongoDB` at a specific interval and we need refresh `KieContainer` so that it will start validating new rules. Scheduling for fetching data from `MongoDB` at specific interval can be done, but how we can refresh `KieContainer` which will be residing in `ApplicationContext` of `Spring`, without starting and stopping application.

We are running `Drools` rule engine integrated with `Spring Boot` Application.
So my issue is i need to refresh `KieContainer` with new `String`, so that it can start validating new rules

Comment: Did you find the solution?